# Precise definition of "wear [something] lightly" wanted

Tags: meaning

I would like a precise definition. Does 'wear' mean 'show'?

From NYT:

> You don’t become president without clawing your way into the Oval
>   Office, but voters prefer pols like J.F.K., Ronald Reagan and Barack
>   Obama who **wear their ambition lightly**.

Comment: I think this question is borderline to be closed as general reference.  The definition of 'wear' is easy to look up, though I suppose it might not be obvious since there are several definitions of the word.

Comment: Anything can be looked up. Quelle cochonnerie.

Comment: But we can't do all the work--it helps to see that the OP did some research before just posting

Comment: What research didn't I do? Didn't I ask if 'wear' meant 'show'?

Comment: @user763554: The EL&U site considers "general reference" to be anything that is readily looked up by a single source - in this case the dictionary.  If you had cited a dictionary definition (showing that you did indeed look it up and were still confused) I don't think anyone would have objected.  For instance: "I think it means this: (cite dictionary definition meaning to show) - is that the right definition of wear in this instance?"

Answer (score 3):

Basically, yes.  It comes from [this definition](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/wear) of wear:

> to bear or have in one's aspect or appearance: to wear a smile; to wear an air of triumph.

In other words:  voters prefer politicians who don't *appear* overly ambitious, even if they really are.